# Laravel - transaction rollback not working

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

i have code for saving user and code for sending mail, but i want to rollback if there is an error with saving or sending mail, this is my code looks like :

```
\DB::beginTransaction();

try{
    $user->save();
    //role
    $user->attachRole($role);
    //send email

    \DB::commit();
    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new ActivationCode($user));
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Berhasil mendaftar, cek email anda untuk mendapatkan kode aktivasi'
    ], 201);    

}catch(\Exception $e){
    \DB::rollback();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'fail',
        'message' => 'Terjadi kesalahan, harap periksa kembali form pendaftaran'
    ], 400);  
}
```

the mail code was intentionally made an error.

the problem: the catch is reached but the data still inserted into the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be firstly send mail, then commit changes.

```
\DB::beginTransaction();

try{
    $user->save();
    //role
    $user->attachRole($role);
    //send email

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new ActivationCode($user));
    \DB::commit();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Berhasil mendaftar, cek email anda untuk mendapatkan kode aktivasi'
    ], 201);    

}catch(\Exception $e){
    \DB::rollback();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'fail',
        'message' => 'Terjadi kesalahan, harap periksa kembali form pendaftaran'
    ], 400);  
}
```

Comment: wow omg, stupid me, so the transaction was commited before email sent and also make it stored into database, thank you so much